# Bottomsheet touch events received by mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, bottom-sheet

I've implemented a bottom sheet inside of the layout containing a map view. 
When the bottomsheet is visible and expanded, when i touch or drag on the bottomsheet, the underling map moves aswell. Is it possible to block the touch events from reaching the mapview?

I've tried using [setFilterTouchesWhenObscured](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(boolean)) without any luck.

ps. I'm not looking to disable the map gestures

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make it clickable adding `android:clickable="true` to it's definition on the XML layout